# How do I access Azure certificate from code?

Tags: .net, azure, certificate, x509certificate2

I have a certificate uploaded to azure and it's in the configuration like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <Role name="MyRole">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
          ...
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="MyCert" thumbprint="CB3611F7D2406AB12094AE9489C50FE1A8B6BFF6" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Is there anything like...

```
X509Certificate2 myCert = Config.Certs["MyCert"];
```

or even similar to get the thumbprint to pull it out of the store directly?  I don't see anywhere in the runtime SDK where I can get the cert or even the thumbprint.

Comment: It seems to me like allowing this kind of access to the certificate would be a *"bad idea"*. Personally, if I had to do this I would probably use a different certificate and add it as a resource. [Have a look here for possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661925/how-can-you-get-a-certificate-in-code-on-windows-azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enumerate the certs.  The standard way to implement this is to add the cert thumbprint as a configuration setting in the csdef/cscfg and then look up the thumbprint at runtime via that configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection matchedCertificates =
                store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "XXXXX", false);

        X509Certificate2 cert;
        if (matchedCertificates.Count > 0)
        {
           cert = matchedCertificates[0];
        }
        store.Close();            
        return cert;
    }
```